# Synchronized block in every method which uses a field

Tags: java, synchronized

This seems to be a pretty frequent question though I didn't find one. Suppose I have this piece of code:

```java
public class MyClass {
    private AnotherClass mField;

    public void changeOne(AnotherClass newOne) {
        // <...> lines of code here
        synchronized (mField) {
            mField = newOne;
        }
        // <...> lines of code here

    }

    public void changeTwo(AnotherClass newTwo) {
        // <...> lines of code here
        mField = newTwo;
        // <...> lines of code here
    }
}
```

Let's say `changeOne()` and `changeTwo()` are called from different threads. Is it enough to  have a synchronized block in `changeOne()` to protect `mField` from changing by `changeTwo()`? Or I need to explicitly wrap each place where `mField` is changed into the `synchronized` block? (please leave behind synchronized methods and others).

Comment: What's wrong with synchronized methods? And what are the "others" that we are to leave behind?

Comment: @TedHopp I just meant that in the real piece of code which produced this question I'm dealing only with a `synchronized` block, not synchronized methods, volatile fields.

Comment: Well, whatever you do, you need to synchronize on a shared lock object, not on the variable that's being modified! (The most obvious convenient lock object for controlling access to a member field is `this`, which is basically what a synchronized method does.)

Comment: @TedHopp Why not on the variable?

Comment: Not on the variable because after the variable has changed, you are no longer synchronized on the variable; you're synchronized on what _used to be_ the variable. Other threads won't be able to synchronize on the object that you have locked, so there will, in effect, be no synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly synchronize all modifications to `mField` using either synchronized block (or) synchronized method. Otherwise more than one thread can change `mField` by executing changeTwo at a time.

EDIT: As Tedd Hopp suggested, if variable is not volatile reads also need to synchronized and lock you get should be on same object.

Comment: So changeTwo won't check if mField is locked without a synchronized block around it?

Comment: @AndreyErmakov: That is correct. Every thread will create a stack while executing a method, so one thread is unaware of other thread changes unless you synchroize.

Comment: @Nambari do you mean when two threads are executing `changeTwo` at the same time, or two threads where first is executing `changeOne` and second is executing `changeTwo`?

Comment: It's not enough to synchronize just the modifications. If a read is not synchronized and the variable is not declared `volatile`, then the reading threads may be using thread-local copies of a stale value even after a synchronized block exits after modifying the variable. See pattern 5 in Brian Goetz's article [Managing volatility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html).

Comment: @WaleryStrauch: Both cases.

Comment: @TedHopp: Agree. Edited answer with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, both Threads must try and aquire the same lock, then if Thread A took the lock first Thread B will be blocked till A releases it. Lock can be any Object common for both A and B, most typical for your case is

```
public class MyClass {
    private AnotherClass mField;

        public synchronized void changeOne(AnotherClass newOne) {
             ...
        }

        public synchronzied void changeTwo(AnotherClass newTwo) {
             ...
        }
```

in this case `this` is used as the lock. It is equivalent (almost) to

```
    public void changeOne(AnotherClass newOne) {
         synchronized(this) {
              ...
         }
    }

    public void changeTwo(AnotherClass newOne) {
         synchronized(this) {
              ...
         }
    }
```

synchronized method is more compact while synchronized block is more flexible. With synchronized block you lock on any object while with synchronized method you lock implicitly either on `this` or for static methods on `class`.

Comment: According to [Section 8.4.3.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6), synchronizing the method is _exactly_ (not almost) equivalent to surrounding the body of the method with `synchronized (`this`) { ... }` (at least for instance methods).